# Can't stop alarm clock on Windows Mobile 10

Tags: windows-10-mobile, alarms

I set up the alarm clock on my phone for 7:20 AM on weekdays. Later on I changed the time to 8:00 AM, but it continues to ring at 7:20. I switch it off and deleted the alarm. Still it continues to ring every weekday, though the alarm isn't even in the alarm list, so I can do nothing to stop it. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you sure that it's the system application (Alarms & Clock)?

Comment: What model are you using?

Comment: That's bug on W10M, restart your phone.. Hard Reset will repair that but i don't recomended to do that

Comment: Maybe i solved this problem. I set time to next day and wait, when alarm clock rang. After that i set time back. Today alarm clock not rang. Wait for next days.

Comment: I am having exact the same. Lumia 930, Windows 10 with alarm and clock.
I will try your trick with set the time.

Comment: Why don't you post your solution as an answer and accept it. It may help other community members who dace similar problems.